# How do I get the row number of a range in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get the row number of a range in Excel, but I can't manage to find a way how to get it. I'm using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim nr As Integer
    Set nr = Target.Row
End Sub
```

When I run it I get: **Compile error: Object required**

I also tried to replace Target.Row with the following:

```
 Target.Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Target.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 Target.End(xlUp).Row
 Target.Offset(0, 0).Row
```

But none of these seem to work either :(

Does anyone have any idea as to what's causing the error?

Comment: `Set nr = Target.Row` Remove the word set

Comment: Also, my practice is changing `Dim nr As Integer` to `Dim nr As Long` In excel 2007 onward, the maximum number of row is 1048576, while VBA Integer is up to 65535 only. "As a rule of thumb never use integer". If you have more than 65535 rows, you will get some strange error.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Ok thanks, that works :-), Larry Ok edited it into Long, thanks for the tip

Comment: @Siddharth Rout, add your comment as an answer so it can be accepted